# NotImplementedError: 'update' not supported on frozendict - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this code on my Odoo v8 module:

```
@api.multi
def button_generate_wh_doc(self):
    context = self._context
    partner = self.env['res.partner']
    res = {}
    for inv in self:
        view_id = self.env['ir.ui.view'].search([
            ('name', '=', 'account.invoice.wh.iva.customer')])
        context.update({
            'invoice_id': inv.id,
            'type': inv.type,
            'default_partner_id': partner._find_accounting_partner(
                inv.partner_id).id,
            'default_name': inv.name or inv.number,
            'view_id': view_id,
        })
        res = {
            'name': _('Withholding vat customer'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'account.wh.iva',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_id': False,
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'nodestroy': True,
            'target': 'current',
            'domain': "[('type', '=', '" + inv.type + "')]",
            'context': context
        }
    return res
```

This is a button action, but when I click it it throws me:

```
File "/home/user/odoov8/odoo-venezuela/l10n_ve_withholding_iva/model/invoice.py", line 427, in button_generate_wh_doc
'view_id': view_id,
File "/home/user/odoov8/odoo-8.0-20161017/openerp/tools/misc.py", line 1280, in update
raise NotImplementedError("'update' not supported on frozendict")
NotImplementedError: 'update' not supported on frozendict
```

Has anybody encounter this kind of error implementing this?

I think it has to do with the order in which the context is called, but Im not really sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To update context try this.

```
context = self.env.context.copy()
context.update({'domain':[('something','=','something')]})
```

Now use this as your context variable.

UPDATE:

The above solution is appropriate for the use case described in this question. However there are many circumstances in Odoo where context is taken from the environment and the above described answer does not really explain how to update the context in that fashion. So in those circumstances you will want to use the with_context() function as described by others on this posting.

```
context = self.env.context.copy()
context.update({'domain':[('something','=','something')]})
self.with_context(context).your_function()
```

In this circumstance self is the object in question which could vary. You can find many examples of with_context() in the Odoo source code.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but you should use with_context() as first option like in @shodowsjedi's answer.

Comment: Your right @CZoellner I think when I responded to this originally I was thinking only of the OP's specific question and not some of the more common circumstances of modifying the context variable. I have updated my answer to demonstrate, and good eye for catching my laziness.

Answer (score 6):

sure you can copy context and use the way you like but, when you copy forezedict it will yield new dict breaking current context, rather i will advise you to use `with_context` methods.

```
self.with_context(key=value,key=value)
```

This will update current environment context and will push forward automatically.

Comment: And how to update request.env.context in odoo controller?

Comment: with_context() method cannot be used in api 7 since no environment ENV variable, it trigger an error. The copy() is better for api 7

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i found this solution [here](https://poncesoft.blogspot.com/2015/03/solucion-error-notimplementederror.html)

So, here is the answer

```py
context = dict(self.env.context)
context.update({key: value})
self.env.context = context
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Links can become broken, so we prefer to summarize the answer in the question body itself.